# I Login And Then... It Takes Me Right Back To The Login Screen

Tags: boot, grub2, login, lenovo

I am using the newest stable Ubuntu Studio (I think). It’s hard to check right now. I type in my password, press Return, and then get a black screen saying

`[ OK ] Started Hold until boot process finishes up.`

And then it sends me right back to the login screen...

I see some responses to similar questions telling me to go to Recovery Mode from Grub. I’m looking at the Grub menu and there’s no Recovery Mode.

I have done a memtest and it’s good. I have tinkered around in Grub but I honestly don’t understand Grub. When I get to the Grub screen I am offered one and only one kernel. Now what do I do?

Comment: Please be specific rather than vague terms like "*newest stable*".  The newest stable is 19.10, however most users on this site refer to 18.04 LTS as newest stable (only counting LTS releases), others refer to newest as the latest .04 release (not sure why, but some do?).  Please be specific.  Have you logged in via text terminal (if your $HOME or user directory is full, a GUI login cannot proceed, but text terminal logins will work allowing exploration & correction).

Comment: FYI:  I just remembered Ubuntu Studio 18.04 was **not** a LTS release, so it's likely you mean 19.10 anyway, but please confirm.  *Ubuntu Studio 18.04 is EOL unless you enabled extended-support yourself*

Comment: I would love to login via tty but I don’t know how.

Comment: I would use <Ctrl><Alt><F4> to switch to term 4, and login there.  `df -hl` (disk free, human output & local drives only) will display space, look for '/home'  if you created separate partition for it, otherwise it'll be in "/" if none was created. I still don't know your release (but switching to text terminal may help you recognize it).  FYI: Use ^D  (<Ctrl><D>) on an empty command prompt to logout

Comment: And without a terminal, I’m not sure how to even check what version is on here. I can get to a Grub terminal only.

Comment: I am pressing Ctrl Alt f4 at the gui login screen and nothing is happening.

Comment: Wait. I got it. (Had to hold down Fn also).

Comment: So is it my /home dir that is likely too full or the /root dir?

Comment: I’m in... ... ...

Comment: GUI  (you haven't said which, Ubuntu Studio implies it maybe XFCE but you weren't sure, and Ubuntu Studio can be loaded on other desktops) requires the creation of work files that are made in /home/$USER/ or your $HOME directory; if this file creation fails, the login cannot proceed and user is returned to the login prompt without error message (login type loop). Also note /  (root) and /root/ are very different directories, /root/ is the user directory for 'root' user, where as "/" is the "root" directory.

Comment: Aaah. Yeah so I logged in via tty, deleted some files (not from /root/ because that would be impossible as far as I know) and... I’m in.

Comment: Thank you! :) ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: Yes. My problem is solved and everything works as normal again. And this also seems to have solved another problem I was having. Thank you!